# Constructing the Stone Space of a Distributive Lattice

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, lattices

Does anyone have a good reference for the method of giving a topology to a distributive lattice as outlined in M.H. Stone's "Topological representation of distributive lattices and Brouwerian logics"? The full reference for that paper is:

M.H. Stone, Topological representation of distributive lattices and Brouwerian logics, ˇCasopis Pešt. Mat. Fys. 67 (1937) 1–25.

But I cannot seem to find an actual copy of the paper. Perhaps there are more recent references that outline the process in more modern terms, or perhaps it is very simply and can simply be described in an answer here. I have heard that the construction involves choosing ultrafilters, but from what I can glean ABOUT Stone's paper (e.g. a 1938 review of it by Saunders MacLane, Stone seems to do things in terms of so-called ideals of the lattice).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Stone spaces" by P. T. Johnstone

Comment: http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/124080/CasPestMatFys_067-1938-1_1.pdf

Comment: Man that's great! Thanks to both of you. I have requested Johnstone's book from the library (it appears that someone has already checked it out!). And wow, Pete that was incredibly quick and concise! Many thanks. 

Comment: Nowadays it is more common to use Priestley spaces to represent distributive lattices. This is so because the presentation is simpler than the one given by Stone. 